# Proof in a Scalar Triple Product

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, vectors

For any three vectors $\vec a,\ \vec b,\ \vec c$, show that :

> $$[\vec a\times\vec b,\ \vec b\times\vec c,\ \vec c\times\vec a]=[\vec a,\ \vec b,\ \vec c]^2$$

where $[\vec a,\vec b,\vec c]=\vec a\cdot (\vec b\times \vec c)$.
Does it employ properties of vector triple product? Please explain the properties involved. We were not taught vector triple product at school. Thanks

Comment: What does it have to do with calculus?

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?

Comment: Square brackets are S.T.P. or Scalar Triple Product as tenpercent specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&[a\times b,b\times c,c\times a]\\
=&(a\times b)\cdot((b\times c)\times(c\times a))\\
=&(a\times b)\cdot(((b\times c)\cdot a)c-((b\times c)\cdot c)a)\\
=&((a\times b)\cdot c)((b\times c)\cdot a)\\
=&[a,b,c]^2\end{align}$$

The first equality follows directly from the definition. The second equality uses the fact $a\times(b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c$. And the third results from $b\times c$ is perpendicular to $c$. The last uses the symmetry of triple scalar product.

Answer (score 0):

As everything's linear, I'd try to prove it for $a = e_x, b = e_y, c = e_z$ and then go to proving the statement for linear combinations of $e_x, e_y, e_z$.

Comment: By the linearity, it suffices to prove it for $a=e_x,b=e_y,c=e_z$.