# Definition of N-commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra

*Warnings:*

1. I am not a mathematician and
   I am asking this question
   out of curiosity.
2. This question might not have
   the correct tags since I'm
   not sure about what this
   question
   is about.

*Background:*

So I have seen the definition of a commutator which is
$ [A,B]=AB-BA$.

I started wondering that is there a definition for $[A,B,C]$? So I started searching and I found the definition for ternary commutator
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_commutator)

In the wikipedia page there is a reference to N-commutator but there is no wikipedia page for it.

I am not sure that how the extension from 2-commutator (original commutator) to 3-commutator (ternary commutator) works. So I can't figure out the definition for N-commutator.

*Question:*

So, I wanna know that how the extension works and what is the definition of N-commutator.

Comment: Your notation for a ternary commutator also has [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associator) [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590977/proof-in-a-scalar-triple-product) common meanings.

Comment: @J.G.,Thanks for pointing out. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary commutator for an associative binary operator adds together products from all $3!$ permutations of $a,\,b,\,c$, but with a coefficient of $1$ ($-1$) for the even (odd) permutations $abc,\,bca,\,cab$ ($acb,\,bac,\,cba$). The $2$-commutator is the same basic idea, although in that case we'd deem such a description "overkill": the even (odd) permutation $ab$ ($ba$) gets a coefficient $1$ ($-1$). The general $N$-commutator is$$[a_1,\,\cdots,\,a_N]=\sum_{\sigma}\varepsilon_\sigma\prod_{i=1}^Na_{\sigma_i},$$where:

- The sum is over all permutations $\sigma$ of $1,\,\cdots,\,N$;
- The Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_\sigma$ is $1$ ($-1$) for even (odd) $\sigma$;
- The product is left-to-right, e.g. if $\sigma$ is the identity operator $\prod_{i=1}^Na_{\sigma_i}=a_1a_2\cdots a_n$.

The $N$-commutator is multilinear, fully antisymmetric and invariant under cyclic permutations, and satisfies$$[a_1,\,\cdots,\,a_N]=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i[a_{i+1},\,\cdots,\,a_N,\,a_1,\,\cdots,\,a_{i-1}],$$e.g. $[a,\,b,\,c]=a(bc-cb)+b(ca-ac)+c(ab-ba)$.Further,$$[a_{\sigma_1},\,\cdots,\,a_{\sigma_N}]=\varepsilon_\sigma[a_1,\,\cdots,\,a_N].$$